# What would be the best configuration for casters for a workbench?

Tags: workshop

I'm planning to build a movable workbench and I was curious what the best setup for casters would be. I was thinking 1 locking at each corner, but that looks a bit overkill. Are two locking casters enough to keep the table in place? What about using chocks instead? The pricing of locking vs. non-locking casters is fairly high so I'm looking for a more economical solution. Also, is there configuration of 1 at each corner appropriate or should I consider adding a fifth caster in the center?

Comment: How heavy is the workbench? What are the dimensions? What is the surface made of? What are you planning on doing on the bench? (eg, two locks may be fine for light work, but if you are putting heavy stuff on it a lot, or hammering on it it may not be)

Comment: It's going to be 5' x 2' about about 30" high. It will have a top work surface and a full size shelf underneath. I was planning to add a vice to it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best set-up for maneuverability plus stability to to allow the workbench to sit on fixed legs.  When you want to move the bench you can implement a jacking system with the casters similar to

[image]

I have seen this implemented with a rope where you can pull the casters down underneath to lift the bench or with a foot operated jack similar to some table saws such as

[image]

Hope this helps you out.  I've tried the casters with 2 locking casters and I've never been happy with the stability of the bench.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I completely agree that fixed legs are best. This inspired me to look into a two wheel system for moving the bench since it'll be pretty light. The basic idea is that you'd have two wheels on one end that are flush with the floor when all the legs are down. Then when you pick the opposite end of the bench up the wheels would take the weight off the legs. I guess its sort of like how a hand truck would work. When I get it all done, I'll post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with using two no swiveling casters on one side (none on the other) and putting a handle on the other. When you need to move it you just lift the handle and pull it around, otherwise it shouldn't move much.